# How do I filter JSON Output of Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, reactjs, filter

The display of the output from the JSON file shown like the picture below.

[image]

This is my code regarding the react side

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.post(BASE_URL + '/filenameFolder')
    .then(res =>
        {
            dataOne = res.data;
            console.log(`Name file :`+dataOne);
            let jsonData = require(`../../component_NodeJS/server/files/downloads/${dataOne}`)
            jsonData.responses.map((details,index) =>{
            return jsonData = details.fullTextAnnotation.text;
            })                                

            var str = jsonData;
            resdata = str.split("/n");
            console.log(`File Content :`+ resdata);               
        })
}
```

How do i filter the output to like something in the QUARRIES style using the LIKE '%123456-V%' using React with JSON ?

Comment: The Json is just the container. If you want to filter, you should probably do that in your actual data source resp. the request.

Comment: The actual data source is FileExample.pdfoutput-1-to-1.json which in JSON format tho